# Como agregar productos al carrito según el numero del contador

Tags: reactjs

Estoy tratando de agregar productos al carrito pero solo logro agregar un solo producto, lo que quiero es segun el numero del counter, que se agregan x cantidad de productos al carrito.

Este es mi state del carrito

```
const [shoppingCart, setShoppingCart] = useState([]);
```

Este es el contador`

```
export const Counter = ({ stock, cardDate, shoppingCart, setShoppingCart }) => {
  const [numCounter, setNumCounter] = useState(0);
  const [btnAddProduct, setBtnAddProduct] = useState(false); //Estado del boton para agregar al carrito

  const addProduct = () => {
    if (numCounter < stock) {
      setNumCounter(numCounter + 1);
    }
  };

  const SubtractProduct = () => {
    if (numCounter > 0) {
      setNumCounter(numCounter - 1);
    }
  };

  return (
    <CounterContainer>
      {!btnAddProduct ? (
        <CounterWrapper stock={stock}>
          <CounterIcon Icon={<GrSubtract onClick={SubtractProduct} />} />
          <h4>{numCounter}</h4>
          <CounterIcon Icon={<GrAdd onClick={addProduct} />} />
        </CounterWrapper>
      ) : (
        ""
      )}

      <AddProduct
        cardDate={cardDate}
        stock={stock}
        numCounter={numCounter} //state
        btnAddProduct={btnAddProduct} //setState
        setBtnAddProduct={setBtnAddProduct} //setState
        shoppingCart={shoppingCart} //state
        setShoppingCart={setShoppingCart} //setState
      />
      <p className="stock">Stock disponible: {stock}</p>
    </CounterContainer>
  );
};
```

Y esta es la logica que uso para cuando hago click en el boton agregar al carrito , se agrega.

```
const addproductsCart = () => {
    setShoppingCart([...shoppingCart, { cardDate }]);
  };
```

Comment: Podrías intentar otra forma de hacerlo. Por ejemplo, hacer un nuevo array con el valor del estado `let shoppingCartCopy = [...shoppingCart]` luego le haces un push `shoppingCartCopy.push({ cardDate })` y por último haces el set del estado `setShoppingCart(shoppingCartCopy)` . A ver si eso te sirve.

Comment: Ah buenísimo, muchas gracias y como hago para tomar el numero del contar y también agregar al carrito, para saber cuantos producto eligieron ?

Comment: Si cada producto que se agrega al carrito está en el estado `shoppingCart`, entonces ya estás agregando los productos al carrito en el momento que estás seteando ese estado con los datos actualizados. Para poder contar cuántos productos hay, debería ser suficiente con hacer un `shoppingCart.lenght`. Eso te dará la cantidad de elementos del array que tiene ese estado. Ya dependerá de ti cómo implementar todo esto, depende de lo que quieras hacer con esos datos.